# difference between ports and service ports?

Tags: port, mesos, marathon

While exploring marathon REST API, I came across two port numbers ( ports and service ports ) defined in the information ( JSON output) given by the following API call-
`curl http://x.y.z.w:8080/v2/tasks | python -m json.tool | less`
The sample output is as:

```
{
  "tasks":[
    {
      "appId":"/test",
      "host":"172.20.75.145",
      "id":"test.1fc922a9-f4c8-11e5-8bff-005056a76a7f",
      "ipAddresses":[

      ],
      "ports":[
        31313
      ],
      "servicePorts":[
        10000
      ],
      "slaveId":"2130f59b-7289-40eb-b24d-72f0c6fe94c8-S1",
      "stagedAt":"2016-03-28T09:33:26.859Z",
      "startedAt":"2016-03-28T09:33:26.936Z",
      "version":"2016-03-28T09:33:26.800Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Does any one know the difference between ports and servicePorts here? Please also add more information.

Comment: Did you read the docs at https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/ports.html already?

Comment: I read it but because of having less exploration on HAproxy, I am not able to get exact necessity of Service port. Can you please explain it in non-technical way.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you found one of the answers useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Marathon documentation:

> servicePort: When you create a new application in Marathon (either through the REST API or the front end), you may assign one or more service ports to it. You can specify all valid port numbers as service ports or you can use 0 to indicate that Marathon should allocate free service ports to the app automatically. If you do choose your own service port, you have to ensure yourself that it is unique across all of your applications.

Let me elaborate on this in the light of the two main network configurations for Marathon, giving some information about them while I'm at it.

## Host Mode

**Use**: default option for Docker applications, only option for non-Docker applications

Under this configuration your application will bind directly to ports of the host.

#### Without using service ports

You can ask Marathon to provide you with, say, any two ports from the host, same which you want to feed to your application. There are two ways to do this in your application configuration file:

```
"ports": [
    0, 0
],
```

or

```
"portDefinitions": [
      {"port": 0}, {"port": 0}
],
```

By doing this Marathon will reserve two ports from the available port range and assign them to the environment variables
`PORT1`, and `PORT2`.
It is very easy then to invoke them directly in your `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ./launch.sh --listen-on $PORT1 --monitor-on $PORT2
```

or in your `cmd` definition in your Marathon configuration:

```
"cmd": "./launch.sh --listen-on $PORT1 --monitor-on $PORT2"
```

#### Using service ports

Say you are running your application in several hosts (running several instances) and you want to be able to connect to your app on any host in a specific port. That is when service ports come in the picture.
By writing in your configuration file:

```
"ports": [
    3000, 3001
],
```

or:

```
"portDefinitions": [
    {"port": 3000}, {"port": 3001}
],
```

... Marathon will STILL assign random ports on the host, it will STILL assign them to the environment variables `PORT1` and `PORT2`, AND it will also reserve the ports 3000 and 3001 for you to use.

It is up to you to use a service discovery mechanism to route traffic from those service ports to `$PORT1` and `$PORT2`.

You can make service ports equal to host ports (for example if you want to avoid having a service discovery mechanism) and have consistent ports for your app across hosts. You can do so by adding `"requirePorts": true` after your ports specification.
The caveat here is that Marathon will only be able to schedule your application in nodes that have these ports available.

## Bridge Mode

**Use**: for Docker applications only

Under this configuration a few specified container ports are bound to host ports.

#### Without using service ports

In this mode you don't use the "ports" or the "portDefinitions" directives, you use "portMappings" instead. By doing so you are effectively telling Docker to map traffic from specific container ports to host ports and vice versa.

You can map container ports to host ports by specifying:

```
"portMappings": [
    { "containerPort": 80, "hostPort": 0, "protocol": "tcp"},
    { "containerPort": 443, "hostPort": 0, "protocol": "tcp"}
]
```

In this case:
 - Setting `hostPort` to 0 makes it, again, choose a random port from the
   available port range. Again these ports are assigned to `PORT1` and
   `PORT2` env variables respectively.
 - Setting `containerPort` to 0 will make it be equal to `hostPort`.

#### Using service ports

As before, you can enable service ports that will be consistent for you application across hosts by specifying them in your config as follows:

```
"portMappings": [
    { "containerPort": 80, "hostPort": 0, "protocol": "tcp", "servicePort": 3000},
    { "containerPort": 443, "hostPort": 0, "protocol": "tcp", "servicePort": 3001}
]
```

Once again it is up to you to use a service discovery mechanism to route traffic from those service ports to `$PORT1` and `$PORT2`.

#### For more information see:

Marathon ports:
https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/ports.html
Docker host mode:
http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/
Docker bridge mode:
http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101/

Comment: In your docker example, does that mean that people will be able to access the service through ports 3000 and 3001?

Answer (score 3):

Basically through service port marathon tells the haproxy(or service discovery) that you listen on this port and I will give you the list of my instances host ip and port where you have to route your traffic. And haproxy use its own routing algorithm to distribute the traffic across the list of instances.